# Laravel validation returns weird message

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have the following code in a controller method

```
   $request->validate([
     'facebook'    => 'URL',
     'twitter'     => 'URL',
  ]);
```

when I provide an invalid data, it fails but returns an improperly formatted message as follows.

I know this can be fixed via Custom validation messages

but for a required field, it shows a proper validation message, What am I missing with URL field

[image]

Comment: I think you need to write url as lower case. So laravel does not transform URL to u_r_l.

Comment: it not wired in laravel it return with _ in each capital letter example 
firstName , massage return will be first_name

url
The field under validation must be a valid URL.
as documentation  url is all small letter

Comment: @HakanSONMEZ, Yep you are right, I used it wrongly, silly me.

Comment: To add to what @HakanSONMEZ said: rule names are case sensitive because they are converted to study case (Str::studly()) to locate the method name to call them. Use lowercase url as he mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it was a typo, according to @JasonGrim

rule names are case sensitive because they are converted to study case `(Str::studly())` to locate the method name to call them.

So rule names are case sensitive. below one fixed the error

```
 $request->validate([
        'facebook'    => 'url',
        'twitter'     => 'url',
 ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

validation parameters should typed in lowercase.

```
$request->validate([
 'facebook'    => 'url',
 'twitter'     => 'url',
```

]);

Comment: Thanks @Hasan, I got it fixed